# Do inline functions have addresses?

Tags: c++, inline

In section 7.1.1 of the book "The C++ Programming Language" the author states:

"inline function still has a unique address and so do the static variables of an inline function"

I am confused. If I have an inline function then it can't have address. Does this happen in C also?

Comment: I think that sentence needs more context. "inline function still has a unique variable" doesn't make sense. Why don't you think that an inline function can have an address?

Comment: Which edition?  I'm looking at the third edition, and cannot see where it says that.

Comment: Accurate quote from the book - "In particular, an inline function still has a unique address and so do static variables of an inline function". This is the last thing in section 7.1.1 - the previous paragraph starts with "The inline specifier is a *hint* to the compiler" (my emphasis). Static variables are covered in section 7.1.2

Comment: @Clifford - I'm looking at the special edition (third edition modified) - an old edition of the special edition of the third edition which lacks an appendix or two. Stroustrup never seemed to master the idea of incrementing edition numbers.

Comment: @Charles, corrected as pointed out. Thanks :)

Comment: @Steve314:  ... or writing clear succinct text!  He should have got K&R to ghost write it; a real turgid pile of that does little to promote the language. ;-)

Comment: The C tag does not belong here because C is a distinct programming language *with completely distinct rules for the `inline` keyword*

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The `inline` attribute is just a *hint* to the compiler that it should try to inline your function. It's still possible to take the address of the function, and in that case the compiler will also need to emit a non-inline version.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

inline void f() {
    printf("hello\n");
}

int main() {
    f();
    void (*g)() = f;
    g();
}
```

The above code prints `hello` twice.

My `gcc` compiler (with `-O`) emits code something like this:

```
_main:
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        pushl   %ebx
        subl    $20, %esp
        call    ___i686.get_pc_thunk.bx
"L00000000002$pb":
        leal    LC0-"L00000000002$pb"(%ebx), %eax
        movl    %eax, (%esp)
        call    L_puts$stub        ; inlined call to f()
        call    L__Z1fv$stub       ; function pointer call to f() (g is optimised away)
        movl    $0, %eax
        addl    $20, %esp
        popl    %ebx
        popl    %ebp
        ret
```

As you can see, there is first a call to `puts()` and then a call to `L__Z1fv()` (which is the mangled name of `f()`).

Answer (score 6):

Inline functions are have addresses if you need one. Standard only says that:

> An inline function with external
>   linkage shall have the same address in
>   all translation units.

Comment: Is that an embodiment or related to the *"as if"* rule?

Answer (score 5):

There is no contradiction.
In parts where an inline function is called, its code can be inlined.
In parts where you use a pointer to function, a non-inline version can be created to have an address.

Answer (score 3):

The inline expansion of the function doesn't have an address, but if that function has a static variable, the variable does have an address. A static variable is basically just a global variable whose *name* is only visible locally (I.e., within the scope at which it is defined). Other variables in an inline function might be allocated on the stack (like they would be if it wasn't expanded inline) or they might just live in machine registers. The important part is that they are still separate variables, and have to act just like the function hadn't been expanded inline at all (unlike, for example, macros, where extreme care is needed to prevent multiple evaluations from causing problems).

Answer (score 0):

They may be inlined at certain call sites but they still exist as normal function in address space.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing the location of the inlined functions object code, with the implications of inlining. Typically we visualize inlined functions as being placed within the calling function at the source code level. What the book is saying is that the variable names, including the use of static within inline functions, are treated just the same as if the function was in fact your typical, stand-alone function.

Furthermore, treatment of functions with the inline keyword, does not guarantee that they will be inlined, and for instances where they cannot (such as when requiring an address), a non-inlined version will be generated.