# undefined reference to conj, conjf, conjl

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, codeblocks

I cannot figure out how to fix this linking problem in GCC.
I am running CodeBlocks 13.12, under Windows 8, GCC+MingWG 4.8.1.
I have created a project having two files:

**main.c**

```
#include <complex.h>
int main(void)  
{  
    double complex (*FUNC)(double complex) = conj;   
    return 0;  
}
```

**test.c**

```
#include <complex.h>  
double complex (*CEXP)(double complex) = cexp;  
double complex (*CONJ)(double complex) = conj;
```

When the project is compiled in CodeBlocks (I use the compiler option **-std=c11**, only),
an error results, saying: "Undefined reference to conj".

I think this is extrange, since the function **conj** is defined in **complex.h**, as function **cexp** is, but the reference to **cexp** seems to work well.

On the other hand, the error is not triggered for the reference to **conj** in file **main.c**.
**(SORRY: It seems that the error is triggered in main.c, also)**

Is this a particular issue of GCC?
How I must configure CodeBlocks to fix this problem?
Thanks in advance.

More information. The compiler window shows these lines in CodeBlocks:

> mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall -g -std=c11 -g -std=c11  -c C:\Users\Machine\Desktop\myapp\myapp.c -o obj\Debug\myapp.o
>   mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall -g -std=c11 -g -std=c11  -c C:\Users\Machine\Desktop\myapp\test.c -o obj\Debug\test.o
>   mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\myapp.exe obj\Debug\myapp.o obj\Debug\test.o
>   obj\Debug\myapp.o: In function `main':
>     C:/Users/Machine/Desktop/myapp/myapp.c:9: undefined reference to`conj'
>     obj\Debug\test.o:test.c:(.data+0x4): undefined reference to `conj'
>     collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

**ALSO:** I've tried to write the option **-lm** in several places on CodeBlocks without any success (for example, in Settings/Compiler/Other options, or Settings/Compiler/Linker, or Project/Build options..., etc.).

**MOREOVER:** The function `conj` is defined as "inline" by MinGW32 in **complex.h**. I souspect that this could be the problem, but using option **-fno-inline** has not any effect.

**NM program:** By following the suggestion of **o11c**, I used the **nm** program. The following output is obtained:

```
<snip, not what was needed>
```

Comment: You may need to explicitly link against the math library (`-lm` flag).

Comment: @IsmailBadawi: And how do I do that in CodeBlocks? I tried to add the -lm option in several places, but it does not work.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think that it's a bug of MinGW, related to the inline definitions in complex.h.

Comment: Neither `inline` or `extern inline` should lead to linker errors. Do you have the `nm` executable to list symbols in your `libm.dll` ?

Comment: @o11c: I run **nm** with parameter **-C** and obtained the output that is shown in the bottom of my question. I don't know if this is useful or correct.

Comment: @o11c: I have not any libm.dll file. By running **nm libm.a** I obtain nothing. Just this:
00000000 b .bss
00000000 d .data
00000000 t .text

Comment: @pablo1977 `nm` on your program is useless, we already know that. Since `libm` is a C library, `nm -C` is a no-op. `nm` on the library (`libm.a` is a static library, is that the only one you have for sure?) should be able to tell what is in it, with appropriate flags. It is quite concerning that there is no symbol output, how large is `libm.a`? On linux it is 2MB.

Comment: @pablo1977 also what website did you download mingw from? There is an old `mingw32` project (that does 32-bit only) and a newer `mingw-w64` project (that does both 32-bit and 64-bit).

Comment: See, this is a major failing of SO ... you are getting comments from well-meaning individuals who have most likely never used MinGW, and who don't know what they are talking about. FTR, `libm.a` does _absolutely nothing_ in MinGW; your issue is likely that you are not including appropriate headers -- `<complex.h>` _and_ `<math.h>` in this case, or that you are using one of the critically broken `mingwrt-4.x` releases, which have been withdrawn by MinGW.org. You should be using `mingwrt-3.21.1`.

Comment: @KeithMarshall:  As you can see in my pieces of code, the header <complex.h> is present. The library <math.h> is nothing to do here, since the function "conj" is declared in <complex.h>. I tried #include'ing <math.h>, without success. I also tried by adding the -lm compiling option, and nothing happens.

Comment: Yes, I did notice you included `<complex.h>`; omitting it is not the problem, in this case -- using a version of `mingwrt` which laks an external implementation of `conj()` _is_ the problem.  `libm.a`, or `-lm` is completely irrelevant; in MinGW it provides exactly one _utterly useless_ symbol, and _absolutely nothing_ of any value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I think I see where your problem is now; you are trying to take the entry-point *addresses* of `conj()` and `cexp()`, which works for `cexp()`, but not for `conj()`. The explanation is that `cexp()` is a real *external* function, for which you *can* obtain an address, but, if you are using a `mingwrt-3.x` predating `mingwrt-3.21`, (or any broken, and now withdrawn `mingwrt-4.x` release), `conj()` is implemented as `__inline__`, with *no* corresponding external implementation, so there is no way to get its address.

I've fixed this issue, in `mingwrt-3.21`, so you should ensure that you are using that, (preferably the `mingwrt-3.21.1` release).

Comment: Keith, the "inline" issue was my first guess, but other users told that inlining has nothing to do with the problem. On the other hand, creal and cimag are "inline", too, in mingw, but it seems that they are real external functions after all. I will try to reinstall mingw to the version you says.

Comment: @pablo: Those who say inlining has nothing to do with the issue are ... shall we say "misguided"; it _is_ the very crux of the problem. See, you are trying to refer to `conj()` by address, but you cannot get an address for a function which does not actually exist as a stand-alone entity, but simply has its body expanded in line, at every point of use. Even "`extern inline`" doesn't magically ensure that an external implementation exists; it is incumbent on the developer to ensure that it is provided.

Comment: I think this is not incumbent on the developer. It's a library issue, since the identifier cproj is stablished in Standard libraries (C99 and C11) as a function, so, if the developer wants to declare a "pointer to function" object, by assigning the value "cproj", for example, this assignment would have to work without any surprises to the developer. My MinGW installation seems to be some TDM-GCC 4.0.*. I will try another version.

Comment: Suggest OP simply wraps the functions in something not inlined.

Comment: Keith: I've installed 3.* version of MinGW32 as you adviced and **the problem is fixed**. So I choose your answer. I think the implementation of compiler+libraries is responsible for this issue: it has to consider a funcion of a standard library "as if" it had an actual address, according to the Standard C specs. It must not be surprises for the developer. On the other hand, it's also a common assumption for developers, as discussed in: [Do inline functions have an address?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318322/do-inline-functions-have-addresses).

Comment: @pablo, By "developer", I meant the developer of the library, so yes, it is incumbent on him ... in this case, the guy who developed `mingwrt` before me got it wrong, and I've fixed it.

Comment: @pablo, TDM-GCC is _not_ MinGW.

Comment: @pablo, the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318322/do-inline-functions-have-addresses) you cited refers, primarily, to C++ inline methods; OTOH, `conj()` is a GCC `__inline__ __attribute__((__always_inline__))` _C_ function; in mingwrt, it is implemented as such _directly_ within `<complex.h>`. Such an implementation _cannot_ generate an `extern` copy -- every translation unit including the header would provide a copy, leading to multiple definition errors at link time. Thus, it is incumbent on the (mingwrt) developer to provide a _separate_ `extern` implementation.

Comment: @abligh, It is all very well to suggest that OP wraps the implementation in something which is not inlined. Unfortunately, that doesn't fix the underlying problem, whereas, `mingwrt-3.21` _does_. Better, by far, to suggest that OP uses the up-to-date version of the library, as he (sensibly) now does.

Comment: @KeithMarshall absolutely - I simply meant as a workaround if he needed it work compile with older versions too.

Answer (score 0):

I turned my comment on Keith Marshall's answer into an answer as well (as it's too long for a comment):

As per Keith Marshall's answer, the problem is that they are inline, *and* that `gcc` is not producing a non-inlined version.

To get around this, add

```
static double complex conj_ (double complex a)
{
    return conj (a);
}
```

etc. - you can take the addresses of these, and if ever `conj` becomes non-inline, the function should optimise out to a simple address of `conj`.

Comment: Well, I have already done something similar, and worked. Anyway, I don't know if to choose this answer as the rigth one, because I still think that me, as a developer, must rely in the believe that **standard library functions** behaves **as if** they were implemented as not inlined functions. In particular, a **function designator** shall be converted to "pointer to function", according to Standard C11.6.3.2.1/4, so the address of the function designator must exists, not matter how.

Comment: As I've already pointed out, in my own answer, this issue is fixed in mingwrt-3.21 and later releases of the 3.x series. This is a workaround, rather than an answer, and is no longer required.

Comment: @KeithMarshall yep - I meant as a workaround in case it's necessary to provide buidl time compatibility with older versions.